# Indexes not being used in join mysql

Tags: mysql, indexing

I'm trying to improve the performace of some query that joins two tables, I've added an index named skuconf for the colum SKUConfig to the table gio_A_Master_SL_temp and, an index named skuconf as well for the column sku_config in the table gio_cat_hist_SL_temp, but I can see by the explain command that the indexes are not being used in the joint of the tables (only in the creation of the derived tables)

here is the query

```
EXPLAIN SELECT
a.Country,
a.MonthNum,
a.CatBP,
a.Cat1,
a.Cat2,
a.Cat3,
sum(a.SKU_sold) as SKU_sold,
sum(a.items) AS items,
sum(a.Revenue) AS revenue,
sum(b.SKU_visible) AS SKU_visible

FROM

        (SELECT
            Country,
            MonthNum,
            SKUConfig,
            CatBP,
            Cat1,
            Cat2,
            Cat3,
            count(DISTINCT SKUConfig) AS SKU_sold,
            sum(OrderAfterCan) AS items,
            sum(NMV) AS Revenue
        FROM
            gio_A_Master_SL_temp

        GROUP BY
            SKUConfig) a


        LEFT JOIN 

        (SELECT
            sku_config,

            count(*) AS SKU_Visible
        FROM
            gio_cat_hist_SL_temp

        GROUP BY
            sku_config) b ON a.SKUConfig = b.sku_config

GROUP BY a.CatBP, a.Cat1, a.Cat2, a.Cat3
;
```

and here is an image of EXPLAIN results

[EXPLAIN RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6zJt.png)

The columns I added the indexes to are type varchar(28) and both of them have the same collation as show by the SHOW FULL COLUMN command

```
SKUconfig   varchar(28) utf8_general_ci YES MUL         select,insert,update,references
sku_config  varchar(28) utf8_general_ci YES MUL         select,insert,update,references
```

I don't know whay the indexes are not being used by join, is there any way I can make the index work for the joint of the tables?. Also any recommendation for improving the query is very welcome. thanks in advance.

Comment: How big are the tables? Using the index and then a look up has a cost, so sometimes is cheapper just do a full scan. Also you arent join the indexed tables. You are creating a temporal table with the `group by`.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Even without the `group by`, the subquerying likely eliminates the indexes from consideration in the `join` (though they might help the separated `group by`s.

Comment: @Uueerdo That is what  I said when mention the temporal table, isnt?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I just thought it was worth pointing out that those temporary tables would not benefit from the indexing.

Comment: That is an invalid GROUP BY -- it does not know which `country` and `cat3`, etc to get.

Comment: Hi to all and thanks for your replies. I wasn't able to reply earlier because I've been really busy.

@RickJames I think I don't quite understand why you mean by this query having an invalid GROUP BY.

Comment: `GROUP BY` _should_ list every `SELECT` element other than aggregates.  When it doesn't, the query is free to deliver any value it feels like.  I brought it up because I don't understand what you are _trying to achieve_.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    (SELECT
        a.Country,
        a.MonthNum,
        a.SKUConfig,
        a.CatBP,
        a.Cat1,
        a.Cat2,
        a.Cat3,
        count(DISTINCT a.SKUConfig) AS SKU_sold,
        sum(a.OrderAfterCan) AS items,
        sum(a.NMV) AS Revenue,
        count(b.SKUConfig) AS SKU_Visible
    FROM
        gio_A_Master_SL_temp a
    LEFT JOIN 
        gio_cat_hist_SL_temp b
      ON 
       a.SKUConfig = b.sku_config
    GROUP BY
        SKUConfig
  ) combine_result
```

Comment: No.  It will logically do the JOIN before doing the individual SUMs and COUNTs.  Hence, the numbers will be inflated.